# How to eliminate redundant in the regular expression?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I wrote a regular expression in PL/SQL to validate custom URLs:

```
'^((http|https):\/\/)?(www[0-9]\.)?(([A-Za-z0-9_-])+\.{1})+([A-Za-z]{2,4}|\'
|| START_CHAR || '[^' || START_CHAR || END_CHAR || ']+\' || END_CHAR ||
')(\/([A-Za-z0-9_-]|\' || START_CHAR || '[^' || START_CHAR || END_CHAR ||
']+\' || END_CHAR || ')+)*(\/)?$'
```

`START_CHAR` and `END_CHAR` are two different constant characters. In my above Regex, `START_CHAR` repeats (four times).

How can I rewrite it with single `START_CHAR` and `END_CHAR`?

Comment: You've tagged this as Java, but your code looks like it's using SQL-style string concatenation. Your title speaks of "optimizing" the regular expression, but your body makes a completely different request, wanting to eliminate redundant mentions of variables. Please improve your post so that it's clear what your actual regular expression is, what type of regular expression it actually is, and what you would actually like to see changed.

Comment: @ruakh thanks for give feed back for me that big mistake i did. now i edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. Regular expressions are compiled to NFAs and maybe DFAs which already compress all your repetitions. Keep it clear, keep it simple, let the computer do the hard work.

Comment: yes compiler did that. but my regex is unclear with repeat chars.

Comment: So clarify it, but don't confuse it with 'optimization'. It doesn't make any difference.